# HTML5 Websql- How to use with Ionic 3 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, web-sql, ionic3

I am trying to put websql api with Ionic 3 and Angular 4

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

When I invoke openDatabase, it shows opendatabase is not a function and the page doesnt load. But in the browser I can see tables created.

Is there a way we can use it Angular 4 and ionic 3?

I added cordova-sqllite-storage. But I am unable to invoke it on Angular4.

Any examples? I dont want to use SQLLite available with ionic native, since this plugin doesnt run on browser.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following.

```
let db = (<any> window).openDatabase('mydb', '', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Comment: _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.

Comment: please describe your answer to know better about this

Comment: since the function (or method) openDatabase() belongs to window object in javascript, for using that inside typescript you must explicitly tell that the function is in it. this is valid for any function inside the window object that you want to invoke in typescript.

Answer (score 4):

I really encourage to see how add plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module

in our case we would like to swap native SQLite by our WebSQl implementation for developer(browser testing) purposes.

```
{provide: SQLite, useClass: SQLiteMock}
```

To do so we have to add above line in app.module.ts in provider section.

Below code is saved as external typescript file and implementing some of default methods from SQLite plugin ( 'create()' in this case). SQLiteObject is implementing executeSql() method.

```
  import {SQLiteDatabaseConfig} from "@ionic-native/sqlite";

  class SQLiteObject {
    db: any;

    constructor(db: any) {
      this.db = db;
    };

    executeSql(queryStatement: string, params: any): Promise<any> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql(queryStatement, params,
            (tx, result) => {
              resolve(result)
            },
            (error) => reject(error));
        });
      });
    }
  }

  export class SQLiteMock {
    public create(config: SQLiteDatabaseConfig): Promise<SQLiteObject> {
      var db = (<any> window).openDatabase('mydb', '', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(new SQLiteObject(db));
      });
    }
  }
```

Now u can normally follow using ionic tutorial
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/

Comment: Consider adding and explanation as to why this code works.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'executeSql' on 'SQLTransaction': Iterator getter is not callable.